# Linkedin asset upload status throws 403

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to upload a video through linkedin v2 assets api. In that after uploading video as "SINGLE_REQUEST_UPLOAD" and while trying to get status of the asset, I'm getting 403 in response.

```
rishi@rishi:~$ curl -v 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/abc123?oauth2_access_token=xxxx'

{"status":403}
```

I have tried same request with `"Content-Type:application/json"` and `"X-RestLi-Protocol-Version:2.0.0"` headers also.
Can anyone help to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same error and reached out to LinkedIn about this, and they fixed it yesterday.

As a sidenote, if you're writing code to deserialize the response of this endpoint, note that the `Recipes.status` returns `AVAILABLE` when the video is ready and not `READY` like the ugc status endpoint does.

Edit: I also reached out to LinkedIn about the documentation on the statuses in the return object, and the schema has been updated on the video upload page to show what values they can take on.